# CloudWatch Events: Schedule Expression Invalid

Tags: cron, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I have written a cron expression below:

`0 13 * * 1-5`

for triggering “At 13:00 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday.”

But when I use it in cloudwatch events I replaced the day of the month with `?` as stated in the aws docs. But this doesn't work and says `Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid`

```
Minute Hour day(of the month)  month day(of the week)
0       13       ?               *       1-5
```

What am I missing here?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508593/8667423).

Cron expressions have six required fields.

It worked after adding an extra `*` for the year field.

Also normal cron syntax uses 0-6 for sunday-saturday but for clouwatch events 1-7 is used for sunday-saturday.

[AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html)