# Terraform AWS - ScheduleExpression is not valid

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create a resource

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "foo" {
  ..
  schedule_expression = "cron(*/5 * * * * *)"
}
```

And I want it to run every 5 minutes. Terraform says this expression is not valid:

```
ValidationException: Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid.
```

What am I doing wrong?

*Note that I don't want to use `rate(5 minutes)` because I want it to run at minutes which are multiplies of 5 (00, 05, 10, 15, 20, [...], 55).*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482314/parameter-scheduleexpression-is-not-valid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
cron(*/5 * ? * * *)
```

[image]

Comment: Taken from cloudwatch docs:
The * (asterisk) wildcard includes all values in the field. In the Hours field, * would include every hour. You cannot use * in both the Day-of-month and Day-of-week fields. If you use it in one, you must use ? in the other.